# c# Multiple files and file streams

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, .net-core

This might not be the best place. I don't have a problem with some code but rather looking for a code idea.

I want to be able to scan a file to a see if the file contains multiple files within, hidden or not.
For example: Take a movie with mp4 extension that movie has a video stream and an audio stream and/or  srt file embedded. you can hide a zip file behind a jpeg file using standard cmd command line.

So I want to be able to scan a file for those multiple hidden files/streams inside. Is there such a way and can anyone guide me packages or code snippet or website?

So far I haven't found anything cause I don't know what too google for.

Comment: are you talking about ADS, i.e. the NTFS feature that allows multiple *independent* streams under the same file? or are you talking about using *specific file format* features to embed one file as metadata (or similar) in another file as part of the payload? or are you talking about just lying in file extensions? or...?

Comment: I'd say that's pretty tough because we rely how we interpret files via file extension (basic).. and now if you knew how .xlsx/.docx files are structured (try adding .zip on them).. it has a collection of files inside it.. but it is also interpreted as 1 file..

Comment: There are many such container/archive/package formats around. You would have to test all (many) of them. Technically a stream/file is just bytes.

Comment: difficult to answer, recently i was hacked, So i tough is there a way i can create a program that can verify a file for example is a movie and not some extra malicious code payload inside. But as i interpret it right even with hidden malicious code payload its still 1 file?

Comment: if you were hacked: burn the machine and rebuild it from your known good state; for scanning files against malicious content, you'd be better off looking for good specialist tools - nothing you do yourself is going to be reliable here, so ... that sounds like you're wasting your time, but: once you've burned the machine, it it moot!

Comment: well i actullay sold my pc and build a new one tought. for this moment i do file verification using filesystemwatcher that actually notifies me whenever a file is added deleted copied accesed and from which process or added by some process. this way i can determine which files that doesn't belong on my computer. and format every now and then.

Comment: or to know for example if you clicked fishing and spyware or malware is being installed and or running in the background that would be usefull coz not every anti virus scanner scans or know that you have got malware, but i'm thinking to do all my browsing within a vm so my p can stay clean